# How do you output the Image Caption on an asset?

Tags: assets, image

When you double-click an asset you can set the Image Caption:

[image]

How do you structure the query to output this Image Caption "field?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give a try:

```
{{ craft.assets.filename('refresh1.png').one().imageCaption }}
```

Where `imageCaption` is the `handle` of your `Image Caption` field (`imageCaption` is an example, you should check this value).

More informations about how to fetch assets: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/asset-queries.html